# Trouble with zxing Gem in Ruby 3.2.1 on Rails 7.1.1: Uninitialized Extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zxing

I'm currently developing a Rails 7.1.1 application using Ruby 3.2.1, and I've encountered an issue when trying to use the `zxing` gem for barcode reading functionalities. Despite following the installation and setup instructions, I'm facing errors related to uninitialized extensions, and I can't seem to get the gem working.

**Error Message:**

I'm encountering a series of "extensions not built" errors when I try to start my Rails server with `rails s`. The errors mention various gems, including `bcrypt`, `bigdecimal`, `bootsnap`, and others, suggesting to try `gem pristine --version` for each.

```
Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.20 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.20
Ignoring bigdecimal-3.1.6 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine bigdecimal --version 3.1.6
...
Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 3.1.4, but your Gemfile specified 3.2.1`

require at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1175
require at uri:classloader:/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/stdlib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:85
```

I've attempted running `gem pristine --all` but the issues persist. Interestingly, when I remove the `zxing` gem from my `Gemfile`, everything works as expected, which leads me to believe the problem might be related to this gem specifically.

I've verified my Ruby version with rbenv versions, ensuring that I'm indeed using Ruby 3.2.1, as specified in my Gemfile.

How can I resolve these errors and successfully start my Rails server? Is there a systematic way to rebuild gem extensions or ensure they're correctly built for my environment? Additionally, does anyone have insights into the issue with the zxing gem and how it might be causing or related to the other gem errors?

Comment: I've confirmed that it works with Ruby version 3.2.1, as I've tested it successfully using just Ruby, and it functions as expected. However, this issue arose when I attempted to use it within a Ruby on Rails project.

Comment: Bundler is reporting that you are using Ruby 3.1.4, while you think you are using 3.2.1. That is where I would start my search for the problem. Why does bundler say 3.1.4, and you think it is 3.2.1? Bundler is most likely not wrong.

Comment: Are you using jruby by mistake?

Comment: OP: Could be interesting trying to use a 10 year old gem (built for compatibility with 1.8.7 and 1.9.2) in conjunction with ruby 3.2 and rails 7.1. @BenTrewern it appears `jruby-jars` is a dependency of the `zxing` gem

Comment: yes the gem depends on jruby